# how to save the meta-information on dotnetnuke page. asp.net

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, meta-tags

i am creating a customize page wherein i am displaying the article, now i have lakhs of articles in database, now i have a facebook shared button on the same page, my problem is whenever user clicks on that button, for some article, it gets the proper title on facebook wall and for some, it displays incorrect information, i came to know from googling, that i need to set the page header (meta information) for facebook to fetch correct information, but now i dont know where does dotnetnuke save the aspx version of the page, i cannot wtite the meta information on the default.aspx page as i want to fetch the title on the article page, so how can i set the meta information on article page, also i want to set the meta information at the runtime, as the information would change for every article, so please reply me how i can set the meta information.....

i am setting the page title on the article page using CDefault class of DNN, and how can anyone tell me how to set the meta information at runtime, is there any class available for meta information too....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CDefault` has `Description`, `KeyWords`, `Author`, `Generator`, and `Copyright` members in addition to `Title`.  Are those not working for you?